# Is possible use 'div id' as name of array?

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, wordpress, frameworks

Please view this jsfiddle [jsfiddle.net/rflfn/uS4jd/](http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/uS4jd/)

This is other try [jsfiddle.net/rflfn/T3ZT6/](http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/T3ZT6/)

I'm using [SMOF](https://github.com/syamilmj/Options-Framework) to developper Wordpress theme, I need make one function to change some values when link is clicked, but when I make array with name of div, the array returns null value...

**HTML:**

```
<a class="button" id="settext1">Some Link</a>
<br />

<a class="button" id="settext2">Another Link</a>
<br />

<a class="button" id="settext3">Link 3</a>
<br />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // var col_settext1 = new Array(); // <-- I need make this array with name of DIV cliked
    col_settext1['field_id1']='#FF0000';
    col_settext1['field_id2']='#00FFFF';

    // var txt_settext1 = new Array(); // <-- I need make this array with name of DIV cliked
    txt_settext1['field_id3']='Some Text Here';
    txt_settext1['field_id4']='Another Text Here';

    // var txt_settext2 = new Array(); // <-- I need make this array with name of DIV cliked
    txt_settext2['field_id5']='Some Text Here';

    // var col_settext2 = new Array(); // <-- I need make this array with name of DIV cliked
    col_settext2['field_id6']='Another Text Here';

    // var chk_settext2 = new Array(); // <-- I need make this array with name of DIV cliked
    chk_settext2['field_id7']="checked";
});

$('.button').click(function(){
    $myclass = this.id;

    $col = 'col_' + $myclass;
    $txt = 'txt_' + $myclass;
    $chk = 'chk_' + $myclass;

    // Based I clicked on the link 'settext1', Here I have this:
    // col_settext1
    // txt_settext1
    // chk_settext1

    // THE PROBLEM ARE HERE!
    $col = new Array(); // <--- Here I use name of DIV as Array, but the value is lost...
    $txt = new Array();
    $chk = new Array();

    // Test...
    alert($col); // <--- Here no have any value :(
    alert($col[1]); // <--- Here no have any value :(

    for (id in $col) { // 'id' is value of array --> col_settext1['field_id1']='#FF0000';
        // do function based on array values...
        // just example:
        alert(id);
    }
    for (id in $txt) { // 'id' is value of array --> txt_settext1['field_id1']='#FF0000';
        // do function based on array values...
    }
    for (id in $chk) { // 'id' is value of array --> chk_settext1['field_id1']='#FF0000';
        // do function based on array values...
    }

});
```

Is possible use name of the div as array name?
Any suggestion or any other method to solve this problem is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask on jQuery forum and finally get the solution
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-possible-use-div-id-as-name-of-array-that-already-have-value

http://jsfiddle.net/L4CDd/

**HTML**

```
<a class="button" data-arr="arr1">Button1</a> |
<a class="button" data-arr="arr2">Button2</a> |
<a class="button" data-arr="arr3">Button3</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
var arr = {
    arr1: {value1:"test 1", value2:"test 2"},
    arr2:{value3:"test 3", value4:"test 4"},
    arr3:{value5:"test 5", value6:"test 6"}
}
$('.button').click(function () {
    var call_array = arr[$(this).data("arr")]
    $.each(call_array, function (index, value) {
        alert('Array Value: ' + index + '        Array Content: ' + value);
    });
});
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (i.e. you want to create dynamic variable names based on certain parameters), you should be using below code instead of "$col = new Array();"

```
window[$col] = new Array();
window[$txt] = new Array();
```

etc..

Comment: I need use Array with same name of DIV id, the array already exist and values to array already exist too, what I need to do is just click the link with an ID and use the array with the same name of ID, but does not work... Please view this code to better understand [jsfiddle.net/rflfn/sZJ37/](http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/sZJ37/), in the window that appears message 'value return blank ...' , I need to show the value that is in the array, but dont return value :(

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not actually setting the variable name to the new array, if I'm interpreting what you're asking correctly.

At this stage:

```
$myclass = this.id;

$col = 'col_' + $myclass;
$txt = 'txt_' + $myclass;
$chk = 'chk_' + $myclass;
```

You'd have 
    $col = "col_id", 
    $txt = "txt_id", 
    $chk = "chk_id".

Basically, each of these three variables is bound to a string.

Now you do:

```
$col = new Array();
$txt = new Array();
$chk = new Array();
```

So now each of these three variables is bound to a brand new array, with no entries in it.

What you want to do is this:

```
$col = new Array();
$col[0] = "col_" + $myclass;
```

And the same for the others. This will create a new array with a single entry, "col_id", bound to the variable name $col.

This will give you arrays named $col, $txt, and $chk containing the id name.

If, instead, you want to actually create dynamic variable names (not sure if you actually need this, but sure), you need to use [Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746155/dynamic-jquery-variable-names).

Comment: Almost this, but this way the values on ​​the array are lost, I need to keep the value it has in the array, and call the array according to the name of the div is clicked, to better understand you can take a look at this code [jsfiddle.net/rflfn/sZJ37](http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/sZJ37/), note that the last window does not return value in the array, that is where the problem lies.

Comment: In this case, you either want to simply append the string to what you already have in the array, or, having used the Window technique (akin to Globals() in Python if you're familiar with that) create the new arrays with the proper names of div IDs and then copy the data into them.

Comment: Yes, it was exactly what I thought, but I have over 200 arrays with different values​​, so I wanted to use only one function, instead of doing 200 functions with virtually the same code.

Comment: I'm not sure which of the two cases you're in, but either way, I think it's best to write a function that takes in an array and a name and binds the two. You shouldn't have to do the same thing 200 times.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something simple, my knowledge in jquery is minimal, I'm two full days trying to make this work and nothing. For who knows this thing is five minutes. I created another code, what I need is just to get the alert returns the desired value, then I can put my original code to work.

By clicking the button1, I should see the alert "text 1", but nothing happens.

http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/N4a2h/

**html**

```
<a class="button" id="arr1">Button1</a>
<a class="button" id="arr2">Button2</a>
<a class="button" id="arr3">Button3</a>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.button').click(function () {

    var window[myvar] = this.id;
    window[myvar] = new Array(); // I need use ID as array name

    // Code for button1
    arr1['value1'] = 'text 1';
    arr1['value2'] = 'text 2';

    // Code for button2
    arr2['value3'] = 'text 3';
    arr2['value4'] = 'text 4';

    // Code for button3
    arr2['value5'] = 'text 5';
    arr2['value6'] = 'text 6';

    // Click on Button1, the alert below need show "text 1"
    alert(window[myvar['value1']]); // "text 1"

    // alert(myvar['value1']);
});
```

I found this
[http://www.sitepoi...post5174213](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?876875-string-as-variable-array-name&s=506f079dd0317e454cb1039f039e143d&p=5174213&viewfull=1#post5174213) but I can't make it work too.

I try use this other [Dynamic jQuery variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746155/dynamic-jquery-variable-names) but I can't make it work too.